# how to wrap span tags around a datatables search input to integrate 'clear search' feature with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I want to add a feature to a datatables search field where clicking on an icon within the input field clears the searched for text.

there is a working clear search jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PJZmv/801/

and i am trying to integrate this with datatables here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/Y37hZ/

these are the steps i have taken:

customise the `jquery.dataTables.js` script by changing:

```
sSearchStr.replace('_INPUT_', '<input type="text" />') :
sSearchStr==="" ? '<input type="text" />' : sSearchStr+' <input type="text" />';
```

to:

```
sSearchStr.replace('_INPUT_', '<span class="clearable"><input type="text" name="data_field" value="" /><span class="icon_clear">x</span></span>') :
sSearchStr==="" ? '<span class="clearable"><input type="text" name="data_field" value="" /><span class="icon_clear">x</span></span>' : sSearchStr+' <span class="clearable"><input type="text" name="data_field" value="" /><span class="icon_clear">x</span></span>';
```

and added this css:

```
/* added clear search css */

.clearable {
position:relative;
}
.data_field {
padding-right:30px; /* add space for the 'x' icon*/
}
span.icon_clear {
position:absolute;
right: 9px;
display: none;
top: -2px;
cursor:pointer;
font: bold 14px sans-serif;
color:#cc0000 !important;  
}

span.icon_clear:hover {
color:#f52 !important;
}

/* end added clear search css */
```

and then added the jquery:

```
$(document).on('propertychange keyup input paste', 'input.data_field', function(){
var io = $(this).val().length ? 1 : 0 ;
$(this).next('.icon_clear').stop().fadeTo(300,io);
}).on('click', '.icon_clear', function() {
$(this).delay(300).fadeTo(300,0).prev('input').val('');
});
```

but as you can see in the jsfiddle it is not working yet.

so the desired outcome is for the 'clear search' feature to be working in the datatables integration as well as it does in the standalone jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your code

```
$(document).on('propertychange keyup input paste', 'input.data_field', function(){...
```

with

```
$(document).on('propertychange keyup input paste', 'input[name="data_field"]', function(){...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you sir! that worked, the only thing is that the results are not 'refreshing' when the input box is cleared (as they would if you highlighted all the text in the input box and backspaced for example).   is there some more aggressive way to make that value afterwards REALLY without data? thank you.

Comment: My suggestion: At the end of your 'click' handler, add:

$(this).siblings('input').trigger('keyup.DT');

Comment: that worked, thank you! i have no idea what it means but it worked, i will look it up now! thanks!